# "493,075 questions with no upvoted or accepted answers" But I never set a filter for "no upvotes"

Tags: bug, search, filtering

It's a very small thing that keeps bugging me, so I decided to take it here.
Whenever I click on my custom filters I see some new text appear at the top left of my screen.

> 493,075 questions with no upvoted or accepted answers

This is what I'm looking at right now "no upvoted".
I really don't care if an answer has upvotes or not. I've never even set a filter for that.
[image]
I only set a filter so the question has no accepted answers.
Why does the text say it is also filtering for "no upvotes"?

Comment: Related:  why would you want a filter for questions with no upvoted answers?  What would you possibly hope to gain from those questions?

Comment: @Makoto questions that "need" answers. Presumably, a question with upvoted answer(s) needs less answers than one without.

Comment: I want the newest questions only. Also what is the point of saying no upvoted answers if there is a filter for no answers.

Comment: @yivi:  I would conjecture that an answered question with zero upvotes doesn't need answers.  There are a lot of factors to explain why an answer isn't upvoted and I wouldn't want some brave and intrepid soul thinking that it's their solemn duty to go around upvoting every zero-scored answer with a filter like this, which is why I asked about it.  Don't get me wrong - I like the idea.  I just don't think there's a whole lot of lasting value.

Comment: @Makoto "I would conjecture that an answered question with zero upvotes doesn't need answers". Exactly, and I think that's the reason the "no accepted answers" checkbox conflates the two. The UI is unclear, but that's how I interpret those results. At no point I imagined the filter as a way to find "0-scored answers to upvote".

Comment: I was interpreting the request as a way to find those kinds of answers @yivi, but I think we're in agreement with one another on this one.

Comment: If you want the newest questions only, then the "answers" filter is irrelevant. The "accpeted" checkbox is conflated with "upvoted" because of what I mentioned above: a question with either kind of answer is less likely to "need" answers than one with an answer that's either upvoted or accepted. I agree that the UI should make this a bit clearer, though

Comment: That's by design. See [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330326/custom-filters-release-announcement#comment1077885_330366). The "No accepted answer" filter has the "unanswered" criteria (no accepted or upvoted answer).

Comment: it is to cry that there a so many unaccepted answers.